# Almost there with recursion. One last thing

Tags: python, list, recursion, concatenation

Thanks to stack overflow I'm almost done with a programming problem that's been driving me crazy. It's recursive, and here's what it looks like:

```
def changeling(word,target,steps):
    x=word
    z=target
    if steps==0:
        return []
    if x==z:
        return [z]
    if len(word)!=len(target):
        print "error"
        return None
    i=1

    if lookup(z[0]+x[1:]) is True and z[0]+x[1:]!=x :
        word=z[0]+x[1:]
    while i!=len(x):
        if lookup(x[:i-1]+z[i-1]+x[i:]) and x[:i-1]+z[i-1]+x[i:]!=x:
            word=x[:i-1]+z[i-1]+x[i:]

        i+=1
    if lookup(x[:len(x)-1]+z[len(word)-1]) and x[:len(x)-1]+z[len(x)-1]!=x :
        word=x[:len(x)-1]+z[len(word)-1]


    return [x]+changeling(word,target,steps-1)
```

if I enter:

```
changeling("find","lose"4)
```

I receive:

```
['find', 'fine', 'line', 'lone', 'lose']
```

Which is the exact output I want. My next step in the program is this. If a word cannot be changed to the target word in a certain number of steps, the function just returns None. So if I were to input:

changeling("find","lose",3)

I should receive nothing, but instead I receive:

```
['find', 'fine', 'line']
```

I'm not quite sure how to do this, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Side note: Incorrect inputs should trigger an exception, not `print "error"; return None`.

Comment: Please don't "format" your code by just indenting the `def` line by four spaces. That produces wrong Python code. Highlight your code and press the `{}` button that you see at the top of the edit box. It will automatically indent your code for you.

Comment: Thank you for that, I didn't realize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of returning immediately the recursion, proceed as follow:

```
y =  changeling(word,target,steps-1)
if y :
  return [x] + y
else:
  return None
```

The problem with your original version is that you return what has been computed with, appended, the following steps. If you can't find a good word to continue the chain, then your program outputs `None`, thus you return statement is composed of  a list of valid steps + None, which is equivalent to only the list of valid steps. Here, all we do is check first if the following step can be achieved, if not we return `None` only, and if yes, then we return everything.

Comment: can you explain how exactly this is changing the program. I'm aware it works, I just can't see why.

Answer (score 0):

You only have to change your final return statement:

I'm not fluent enough in python to give you the exact code, so here's pseudo code:

```
subReturnValue = changeling(word, target, steps-1)

if(subReturnValue.length == (steps-1)) then
     return [x] + subReturnValue
else
    return []
```